# typing into an input field using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Visits Replpad', () => {
    cy.visit('http://hostilefork.com/media/shared/replpad-js/')
    cy.get('input').type('now')
  })
})
```

Trying to type some text into the bottom input field but it times out trying to find the input field.  I've extended the time out period up to 10,000 but it still doesn't see the input field.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Please show the dom structure of you page

Comment: The console appears here https://github.com/hostilefork/replpad-js/blob/master/index.html#L121 in consult_out, and is created here https://github.com/hostilefork/replpad-js/blob/master/replpad.reb#L350

Comment: why not just look into the DOM as it shown in the Cypress runner after you've execute your test? It shows it exactly as it was at the moment when Cypress was trying to find the `input` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

`cy.get('input').type('now')`

try

`cy.get('.input').type('now')`

because you are looking for the class name not for the tag
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I had only installed cypress last night so must have misread the docs.